# choosing the right EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am currently working on a file sharing android project for my college, in which I want to use aws EC2 instance as my application server backend. But which EC2 instance should I have to use? I am very much confused about this.

My server contains few PHP scripts for Login, signup,and operations on database(adding rows of a shared file link, deleting..etc) I am using aws S3 to store the files before sharing the link of the file. Sharing the link is done over TCP/IP sockets. So I even want to use the same server for the socket server. There are many instance types here https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ . But don't  know which one to use for my particular project.

Comment: I am voting to close this question off topic because it is too broad.  It is not possible to give you a meaningful answer, because it depends on too many factors.  Start with the cheapest instance class that intuition tells you is sufficient for your workload, such as t2.micro, and then, if you have issues, identify places where your code is sub-optimal, and optimize it -- or scale up the instance for the type of resource you need more of (e.g., CPU, memory, network bandwidth).  Changing a running machine to different instance takes maybe 2 minutes.  Don't agonize over the initial choice.

Comment: TLDR: test it "for [your] particular project".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to choose from http://www.ec2instances.info/ but honestly the decision remains up to you.

The only thumb of rule is : "start with small instances and get big when needed" - define some alerts about your CPU/RAM usage of your instance and then go to a bigger one when needed

Comment: what do you mean by "define some alerts about your CPU/RAM usage"? will you be more clear?

Comment: you can read and set [cloudwatch alarms](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/ConsoleAlarms.html) so that you receive notification when your instance (or other aws services) reach a certain level of `metrics` (metric can be CPUUtilization, Disk Usage ...) so you know if you need to upgrade your instance